# get X amount of posts with user from every category - eloquent orm

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

What's the minimum amount of queries needed for this operation?

`category->hasMany(post)`

`post->belongsTo(user)`

The only thing I can come up with is:

```
    $categories = Category::all();
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $category->posts = Post::where('category_id', $category->id)->take(4)->get();
    }
```

Say I got 4 categories the output of the query log will print 9 line of queries.

Comment: Not sure this will affect the answer, but shouldn't the relationship between `Post` and `Category` be inverted?  ie. so that `post->hasMany('categories');`?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, I thought post->belongsTo('category') was implied when I wrote category->hasMany('post')

Comment: no worries, it just seemed strange to me expressed that way :).  Have you tried adding a method to the `Category` model that pulls down the most recent `x` posts?  that way you could get it down to just `x + 1` calls.

Answer (score 0):

here's a quick example of what I mentioned in the comments. By defining a method on your Category model, you can reduce the number of calls you make for each category to 1:

*(note: this is a [many-to-many relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many))*

**Category model (Category.php)**

```
class Category extends Eloquent {

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany("Post");
    }

    public function getRecentPosts($n)
    {
        return $this->posts()->orderBy('created_at')->take($n)->get();
    }
}
```

**Posts model (Post.php)**

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany("Category");
    }

}
```

Then you can just call the `getRecentPosts($n)` method to get `$n` posts!

```
foreach (Category::all() as $category) 
{
    $posts = $category->getRecentPosts(4);

    foreach ($posts as $post) 
    {
        echo $post->name . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

You will be making `$n + 1` queries.. one to get the `Category::all()` and then one for the `Posts` of each `Category`...

hope it helps!